# PHP Code Returning the same datetime every time on server with ubuntu

Tags: 16.04, php

I set this at the start of the script :

```
date_default_timezone_set('Europe/London');
$var = date('h:m:s', mktime());
echo $var;
```

And it outputs this everytime, the only thing that changes is the seconds.
    12:12:32
    12:12:45
    12:12:10

Any help with this would be great :)
thanks, Pablo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pablo welcome to Ask Ubuntu!
This Stack Exchange is designed for questions specifically about Ubuntu, for questions regarding programming like PHP, I suggest you try over at [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/) in future.

Regardless, you're time format is incorrect.

`h` refers to the month, since we're in december, it's showing you 12.

Minutes are formatting as `i`

so `$var = date('h:i:s', mktime());` will get you the results you need.

See the official documentation [here](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.date.php) for further info.